# Run Python scripts online

Tags: python, web-services, web

I'm looking for a website or any other method that will allow me to run large python scripts that take long to finish, for free.

I'm not looking for a normal online python interpreter.

It has to allow network connections. Example: opening websites with urllib
It has to have custom library's or allow me to install some. Example: beautifulsoup
It has to allow scripts to run for more than 5min. More or less 5min, 30sec won't do.

I know this is a tall order, but my internet speed,bandwidth and processors aren't enough for my ambitions.

Pay'd service will be a pain for me because working with paypal from my country is a slow and painful process, but if its worth it, please share.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You sound like you're going to try and take over the world. What are you hoping to do here?

Comment: Perhaps you can use an AWS EC2 Micro instance and run your code on it! A Micro instance is (or at least used to be) free for the first year.

Comment: Are you planning a DoS / DDoS attack?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check http://pythonanywhere.com/ You will get 100 CPU seconds / day and 512MB storage in their free plan. You can install libraries through pip and choose what version of python you gonna use. But with free plan, you have access only to whitelisted sites. (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) Also, you can easily upgrade to paid programs (from $5/month) where you can customize how many CPU or HDD you will need. And you can pay by credit card too.

Answer (score 1):

you may give [koding](https://koding.com/) a try.
if you describe your purpose more I might be able to help you more. :)