# Run Python online but share only the output

Tags: python

I've seen this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921910/run-python-scripts-online), but it doesn't really answer my question.

The question: Is there any way I can run my Python script (on 2.7) on a server/website (can be free or paid..or course free would be better), **but without sharing the source code**?

I would like to provide only the output of the script by sharing a link.

I already know some websites, such as [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) .

But on this website, I need to share the source code. I would need to protect the source, as it contains sensitive data.

Comment: In principle, why would this be a problem? The server can execute whatever it wants without the user ever seeing the code.

Comment: run your own webserver and you can provide anything you want.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. PythonAnywhere doesn't make your source code public, and there's no way you can use *anything* without putting your code on it.

Comment: People are fast with the downvotes these days O_o

Comment: @timgeb it's a problem because the script contain passwords ....

Comment: @brian i don't own any webserver. your reply is useless

Comment: @jonrsharpe i wonder if you can use the pythonanywhere to run a script, provide me the link to get the output and do not allow me to see your source code. nobel price for you dude

Comment: The categories for a Nobel are *"chemistry, economics, literature, peace, physics, or physiology or medicine"*, rudimentary programming is not included. That said: http://textbook.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: Thanks. Turing Award for the endless university researchers with physics degree:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Pyhton code contains sensitive data, you should not upload it to a server that you don't own.

So my best advice would be:

1. Get a server. That could be your desktop via some form of dyndns or an inexpensive virtual host.
2. Run your script in a Python framework. Common frameworks are [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Or execute Python using mod_wsgi directly in apache.

Comment: thanks steffen for your reply.